# "It is not a known persistent type" when trying to save Spy object Grails 4.1.2

Tags: grails, save, grails-orm, spock, spy

I cannot save to database object which is spying on other object. That makes testing more difficult.
Is there any workaround to this problem or do you know if it is intentioned? I am not sure if this is an bug or not.

**My testing code**

```
// grails-app/domain/Person.groovy

class Person{

    String name = ""
    String surname = ""

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'identity'
    }
}
```

```
// src/test/groovy/PersonSpec.groovy

import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class PersonSpec extends Specification implements DataTest {

    def setupSpec() {
        mockDomain Person
    }

    def "persist person"(){
        setup:
        Person person = new Person()
        when:
        person.save()
        then:
        true
    }

    def "persist spy"(){
        setup:
            Person person = Spy()
        when:
            person.save()
        then:
            true
    }
}
```

```
// build.gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
version "0.1"
group "testapp"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
}
```

```
# gradle.properties

grailsVersion=4.1.2
```

First test passes, second not.

**Error message:**

```
Object [Person : (unsaved)] cannot be persisted. It is not a known persistent type.
org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NonPersistentTypeException: Object [Person : (unsaved)] cannot be persisted. It is not a known persistent type.
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.persist(AbstractSession.java:591)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.doSave(GormInstanceApi.groovy:365)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save_closure5(GormInstanceApi.groovy:180)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:40)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:179)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:119)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:107)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMethodInvoker.respond(ByteBuddyMethodInvoker.java:20)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockInvocation.callRealMethod(MockInvocation.java:59)
    at org.spockframework.mock.CallRealMethodResponse.respond(CallRealMethodResponse.java:30)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.handle(MockController.java:50)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockInterceptor.intercept(JavaMockInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyInterceptorAdapter.interceptNonAbstract(ByteBuddyInterceptorAdapter.java:35)
    at PersonSpec.persist spy(PersonSpec.groovy:23)
```

Isn't that the spy object should use original object method when there is no mocks? Then above should work. This is simplified version; in my current project I generate Person object with some data to each test and then use it to create Spy with `personObject = Spy(personObject)`.
Gradle version 5.6.4

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to open this as Spock issue. But either way, it would most probably be helpful if you can provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A wild guess without more information could be that maybe Grails checks specific classes for being persistable and does not support subclasses of it which is the case if you Mock it with Spock. Maybe it can be mitigated by using `PersistentEntity` as `additionalInterface` or similar, but hard to guess without an actual example at hand.

Comment: @Vampire I added my build.gradle and gradle.properties files. There is no more files in project. What do you mean by "actual example"? There is one above. Also I made bug report on Spock github as you suggested.

Comment: Now it is, yeah. Before it missed the "C" and "V" of "MCVE". :-)  It is as I supposed. The `AbstractSession` class of `grails-data-mapping` has a hash map with the class instance as key and the according persister as value. The actual class of the spy instance is a subclass of the original class, so the persister is not found. The code also suggests it should work if you define `PersistentEntity` as `additionalInterface` of the Spy and make its `getJavaClass` method return `Person`. From a quick try it did not work. But as it is an ancient version of Spock, it could well be better working now.